# Amazon S3 static Website accessible (403 Error) when secure transport policy added

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an Amazon S3 static website and it was working fine until we introduced a policy where we allow only secure data transfer by enforcing `aws:SecureTransport`. A policy with simply denies access to the site when the `aws:SecureTransport` fails. But when we access the site now, it says `403 Forbidden` error.

The set up is that we have *CloudFront* fronted to this site, so the traffic routes through the CloudFront, not sure if this has to do something with the issue we are facing, where the traffic route between CloudFront and Amazon S3 is *http* only. Having said that, strangely when we tweek the policy to have `aws:SecureTransport:true` and allow such requests to the site, it works fine, but when we have deny policy `aws:SecureTransport:false`, then we end up getting `403 error`. Sharing both the policies here.

When we have this the static website works fine:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowOriginAccessIdentity",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.domain.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ForceSSLRequest",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.domain.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where as when we have as below, it fails, and we want this to be implemented to be absolutely sure:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowOriginAccessIdentity",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.domain.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ForceSSLRequest",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.domain.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Update: I have a policy as below allowing an OAI accessing the S3. This does not work, but when we read/understand the policy it makes sense to allow access the webiste, but it fails :(.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowOriginAccessIdentity",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-domain.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the below works, even though logical readability is same according to my understanding.

```
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowOriginAccessIdentity",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
                },
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-domain.com/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                        "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Any help in understanding this behavior is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you intend the second example to show a `Deny` policy with `aws:SecureTransport:false`? A bucket will remain private until an Allow policy is added, so simply adding a Deny policy will not grant access to the bucket.

Comment: Yes, we also have an allow statement, which is not included here. Along with allow statement when have either of above mentioned ones, the behaviour differs as explained.

Comment: Your two examples seem to be the same??

Comment: My bad. I now added the complete bucket policy for both the scenarios specified.

Comment: If that 2nd policy is failing then, yes, it suggests that CloudFront is not use HTTPS to retrieve content.

Comment: If that holds good, then the second one also shouldn't allow access to the site as policy says if it is securely requesting the Allow. I mean both policies should ideally have same effect. false and deny. true and allow.

Comment: The first policy is granting access via OAI, and ALSO granting access to anyone as long as it is via HTTPS. Thus, the bucket is public. The second policy merely grant access via OAI, as long as it is via HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry about my typo, the first policy also should ideally block the request correct ? As it isn't https from cloudfront and we are allowing only when it is secure (https).

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to wrap my head around your last comment 

Comment: The first policy has two statements. The first one permits access via OAI. The second statement permits anyone to do anything to that S3 bucket as long as requests come via HTTPS. This includes uploading content, deleting content and I think they can even delete the bucket. It is unwise to create bucket policies that Allow `s3:*`.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I have updated the question. Would you please care to check the last two policies, I have added and share your understand.

Comment: Your first updated policy is denying access via OAI if Secure Transport is False, but **does not `Allow` any access**, so CloudFront is _never_ being given permission to access the bucket. (A Deny simply removes permissions previously granted by an Allow. The default is always Deny, so if there is no Allow, then there is no access.) The second updated policy is granting access via OAI if Secure Transport is True.

Comment: Okay. My understanding was if the condition is met then it should take the action of denying else it should allow. But the point you made, cleared the cloud over the understanding that if there is no allow then nothing goes through :thumbsup. Thank you so much for sharing your thoughts and knowledge :immensely thankful.

Comment: The third bullet point, guess there is a typo "Use Deny to override access given by Deny". It should be Use "Deny to override access given by Allow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy logic is:

- Explicit Deny by default
- Use `Allow` to grant desired access
- Use `Deny` to override access given by `Allow`

[image: Policy evaluation logic]

Therefore, the better policy is to `Allow` access if `aws:SecureTransport` is true, since it is less permissive and doesn't need any `Deny` statements (which are always confusing!).

See: [Policy evaluation logic - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html)